# How should i clip time and timezone android

Tags: android

I'm getting server response for date as

```
"commented_on": "2017-04-06T14:01:23Z"
```

Out of this i only need `"2017-04-06"`
That is i want to clip the time and timezone when displaying the date to the user? How shall i do this ?

Comment: use string.substring(0,10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String wanted = "2017-04-06T14:01:23Z".split("T")[0];`

Comment: How can i convert this as Posted on April 04, 2017

Comment: @user7796820 https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/